# bringing just one worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

Here is a code I have to bring in worksheets from another workbook.
But what I need is to only bring one worksheet (not all of them).
I also need macro to rename the worksheet to something other than what it's called in the original workbook that it's imported from. Can anyone help me with those two tweeks?

Here is what I have:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Bring_Workbooks_Click()

Dim directory As String, fileName As String, sheet As Worksheet, total As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = "access path to where the original workbook is stored"
fileName = Dir(directory & "Name of workboork where sheet will be copied from.xls")

Do While fileName <> ""
Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)

For Each sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
    total = Workbooks("Name of my workbook.xlsm").Worksheets.Count
    Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(sheet.Name).Copy _
    after:=Workbooks("Name of my workbook.xlsm").Worksheets(1)
Next sheet

Workbooks(fileName).Close
fileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: How do you identify which sheet you want to copy from the source workbook?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

Sub Bring_Workbooks_Click()

```
Dim path, fileName, WkshtOrig, fullName, MyWkbk  As String
Dim total As Integer

path = "C:\VBA\"  'access path to where the original workbook is stored
fileName = "OrigWkbk.xlsx" 'Name of workbook where sheet will be copied from.xls
fullName = path & fileName
WkshtOrig = "My Orig Wksht" 'name of worksheet to be copied & placed in this workbook.
MyWkbk = "StkOvrFlwuser3738555.xlsm" 'What I named my sample workbook

Workbooks.Open fileName:= fullName

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(WkshtOrig).Copy _
    after:=Workbooks(MyWkbk).Worksheets(1)
Workbooks(MyWkbk).Worksheets(WkshtOrig).Select
ActiveSheet.Name = "MyNewName"

Workbooks(fileName).Close

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```